# Adding driver for Prolific USB-RS232 PL2303 Converter to Linux Build for MYB-AM335X

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, buildroot, usbserial

I have an AM335X TI Development board which can be found [here](http://www.myirtech.com/list.asp?id=467). I believe it is based on a Texas Instruments AM335X CPU module.

I am using Buildroot to build the Filesystem for this board and I need to use USB-Serial converters. I know that FTDI USB-Serial converters are compatible with this board, however I want to use the USB-Serial converters using the Prolific PL2303 chipset.

In the buildroot directories is the source code for the PL2303 drivers "pl2303.h" and "pl2303.c". How could I compile a kernel module for this AM335x board for my specific architecture, even better yet, use buildroot to compile the pl2303.h and pl2303.c source files to include them in my Filesystem?

Comment: I assume you want to connect the USB side of the PL2303 to the board and the UART side of the PL2303 to something else (PC, peripheral chip...). In that case see my reply; otherwise you need no driver at all.

Comment: @LucaCeresoli hey, I have been searching web and came accross your comment here. I will buy an STM32F407VG-DISC dev board. I did usb-ttl serial communication before between same board and a PC with windows10 OS. (ttl side to board and usb side to computer). However, this time, I am running on ubuntu 20.04. What will I need to do to make it work? Any driver installations? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PL2303 driver is in the mainline Linux kernel, so it's very simple:

```
make linux-menuconfig
```

The just enable `USB_SERIAL_PL2303` (`USB Prolific 2303 Single Port Serial Driver`). It's under the `Device Drivers` -> `USB support` -> `USB Serial Converter support` menu, where you can easily find it using the menuconfig search feature.